# Debugging LINQ statement on QuickWatch or somewhere else

Tags: visual-studio, linq, debugging

Is there any way to write linq statements while project is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As linq statements involve Lambda expressions, which are a compiler feature, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work for OzCode*

First of all **Visual Studio 2015** supports [Lambda expressions in the Watch window](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015/)

Bu if you want to debug LINQ you need to either transform it to *ForEach* or [try OzCode's LINQ debugging feature](http://o.oz-code.com/LINQ_EAP).